# Solution of an ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to solve the following ODE:

$$y''(x)+\left( k_0^2-\frac{\lambda}{1+\cosh^2(ax)}\right)y(x)=0 \qquad k_0,\lambda,a>0$$

when as $x \rightarrow \infty$ the solution is of the form $y(x)=e^{ik_0x}$.

My attempt: I did the folllowing substitution $t=-\cosh^2(ax)$ and the ODE which came up was $$ 4a^2t(t+1)y''(t)+2a^2(2t+1)y'(t)+ \left( k_0- \frac{\lambda}{1-t} \right)y(t)=0$$ And then I can use the frobenius method.

The **problem** is that it gets quite complicated with all the regular singular points and also that I don't use anywhere the form of the solution for large x.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Your asymptotic solution, as written, is wrong. Either the equation should involve the term $k_0^2$, or your solution should involve $e^{i\sqrt{k_0}x}$

Comment: It is also my experience that such problems often have solutions in terms of hypergeometric functions, or can be solved by approximate methods such as the WKB approximation. Is the exact form of the spatially variable coefficient important, or is just the shape what you are after? For example, I think the $\frac{1}{1+\cosh^2(a x)}$ can be pretty well approximated by a gaussian function, something like $\frac{e^{-a^2x^2/2}}{2}$. Being a common shape for what I think of as the "index of refraction profile", it's more likely to have been solved by someone else.

Comment: @rajb245 About your first comment: it could be a typo.
I would like to have an exact form. Can you give any advice on how I could turn the initial ODE into a hypergeometric DE or how I could use the solution for large x?

Comment: If there is a typo, please correct it from the original source. Is this from a book?

Comment: Yes, or you can have $y''+k_0^2y=0$, which gives the correct asymptotic form. Please write a consistent equation and asymptotic solution you want to solve, and we can go from there. I can't make assumptions about what equation you want to solve.

Comment: My guess would be $y''(x) + \left(k_0^2-\frac{\lambda}{1+\cosh^2(a x)}\right)y(x)=0,$ but I'm just not sure this is what you want. There are other possibilities. Also, please go ahead and name the text and author.

Answer (score 0):

$4a^2t(t+1)y''(t)+2a^2(2t+1)y'(t)+\left(k_0-\dfrac{\lambda}{1-t}\right)y(t)=0$

$4a^2t(t-1)(t+1)y''(t)+2a^2(2t+1)(t-1)y'(t)+(k_0t+\lambda-k_0)y(t)=0$

This belongs to a [Heun's Equation](http://dlmf.nist.gov/31.2).